# Getting list of IDs to the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Could anybody help me with the following. I need to create an array where I put IDs of all checked radio buttons. I have tried the following:

```
var checked = [];
$('.tsg input:checked').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    checked = checked.push(id);
});
```

But it says

```
Uncaught TypeError: checked.push is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checked.push(x)` returns `x`.

By typing `checked = checked.push(x)`, you're replacing `checked` with `x` on the first iteration, after which `checked` is no longer an array and has no `push` method.

`push` modifies the array in place, there is no need for assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer, it seems to be working now, so the final code is var checked = [];
$('.tsg input:checked').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    checked.push(id);
});

Comment: Once again, thank you. I need to wait 7 more minutes to mark your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map() to create the array for you.

```js
const checked = $('.tsg input:checked').map((i, el) => el.id).get()

console.log(checked)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tsg">
  <input id="1" type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input id="2" type="checkbox" checked/>
  <input id="3" type="checkbox" />
  <input id="4" type="checkbox" checked/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this jQuery method as well!... Update: it works! I appreciate you added the full code snippet!